# Link HTML em RichEdit

Tags: delphi

Seria possível ter um *hyperlink* em uma palavra ou frase em um `RichEdit`, sendo que ao passar o mouse sobre esse link o cursor fique como `crHandPoint` e ao clicar, evidentemente abra o navegador com um site específico.
Por exemplo:
Quando você clicar aqui abrirá o [StackOverFlow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível sim, difícil de compreender mas fácil de implementar/modificar.

Encontrei uma solução e consigo detalhar algumas partes.

Primeiro devemos criar uma `proc` para trocar mensagens com o `TRichEdit`:

```
var
  vEvento: Word;
begin
  FWndProc := RichEdit.Parent.WindowProc;
  RichEdit.Parent.WindowProc := REditParentWndProc;

  vEvento := SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, vEvento or ENM_LINK);
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, Integer(True), 0);
```

Aqui estaríamos informando ao componente para que ele se atualize sempre sua tela quando houver mudanças, responsável por isto é o `EM_GETEVENTMASK e EM_SETEVENTMASK`. Em seguida o `EM_AUTOURLDETECT` detectara todas as URL que existir (aqui com um pequena melhoria você consegue até mesmo digitar no componente e ele reconhecer como uma nova url).

Criamos uma Lista de Links para interceptar no momento do Click ou movimento do mouse:

```
  vListaLinks := TStringList.Create;
  vListaLinks.Add('https://pt.stackoverflow.com=https://pt.stackoverflow.com');

  RichEdit.Text := vListaLinks.Names[0];
```

Foi o que eu quis dizer antes, aqui já possuímos um Link pré-definido, necessário uma modificação para que ele detecte novos links.

Segue toda procedure que sera responsavel pela troca de mensagens:

```
SeuForm = class(TForm)
...
private
  { Private declarations }
  FWndProc    : TWndMethod;
  vListaLinks : TStringList;
  procedure REditParentWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
end;

procedure REditParentWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
 i          : Integer;
 vLink      : TENLink;
 vUrl,
 vLinkFinal : String;
begin
  FWndProc(Message);

  if (Message.Msg = WM_NOTIFY) then
  begin
    if (PNMHDR(Message.LParam).code = EN_LINK) then
    begin
      vLink := TENLink(Pointer(TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr)^);

      if (vLink.msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then
      begin
         SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, LongInt(@(vLink.chrg)));
         vUrl := RichEdit.SelText;

         if (vListaLinks.Count > 0) then
         begin
           for i:= 0 to Pred(vListaLinks.Count) do
           begin
             if vListaLinks.Names[i] = vUrl then begin
                vLinkFinal := vListaLinks.ValueFromIndex[i];
                Break;
             end
             else
             begin
               vLinkFinal := vUrl;
             end;
           end;
         end;

         ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(vLinkFinal), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
         RichEdit.SelStart := 0;
      end
    end
  end;
end;
```

[Fonte](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22000916/Make-a-text-clickable-in-a-RichEdit-to-point-to-a-specific-url.html)